# Why can I access private non-static class properties in a static class method?

Tags: c#, visibility

I just noticed that the following code compiles without an error:

```
public class Foo
{

    private string identifier;

    public Foo() { }

    private static void Bar(Foo foo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{foo.identifier}");
    }

}
```

Since `Bar` is static, shouldn't this throw an exception that `identifier` isn't visible?

Comment: Why should it? `identifier` belongs to the instance passed to the method. Its a normal instance-member of that instance.

Comment: access modifiers control *classes*, not *objects*.

Comment: Because the code accesses the passed in parameter, I don't see what your confusion is here.

Comment: You are passing an **instance** of `Foo` inside your static method. What error do you expect to get?

Comment: It's not because the community is "ridiculous". If you hover on the downvote arrow, the reasons are 1) no research effort (and I don't see any) and 2) Not useful (which it isn't to anyone with even a basic understanding of C#). It's just a fairly basic question with an obvious answer as long as you understand the basics of this language.

Comment: [private](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx) - it doesn't say anything about static methods here. The only limitation is that the methods are declared in the same class, which they are.

Comment: @MichaelPittino Maybe you could A) explain the reasoning behind your belief that static methods shouldn't have access to private instance members, and B) explain exactly what you want us to tell you about it. Your question seems to amount to "I guessed wrong about what this keyword meant. Shouldn't they have checked with me before they designed the language?" Well, maybe, I dunno, but don't hold your breath for a call before they design the next one.

Comment: This community isn't ridiculous. There's just far more chaff than there is wheat. As DangerZone said, it doesn't look like there has been any research effort here.

Comment: When you find yourself saying "this language feature is completely backwards and nonsensical", there are two possible explanations: One is that the language designer didn't bother trying to think through the implications of the decision he made. Can you guess what the other explanation is?

Answer (score 4):

identifier is a member of Foo ...

foo is a parameter of the static method Foo.Bar

foo refers to an instance

the instance is accessed by a static method of its own class...

works fine